# How to NIntegrate a result derived from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have the following code. My requirements are:

1. I want `dp` at `y = h1` for different values of the parameter `x`. I need a plot `x` vs. `dp` (when `y = h1`) when `x` is in `[0,1]`. Besides I need two column values of `dp` for different `x` when `y = h1`.
2. I want a numerical integration using `Nintegrate` of `dp` over `x` from `0` to `1`.
3. I want to plot the integral values with the parameter `F`.

The original problem is more complex. This is a minimal example. Please help.

```
a = 0.7; b = 0.5; d = 1; F = 0; x = 0.1;
h1 = 1 + a Cos[2.0 Pi x];
h2 = -d - b Cos[(2.0 Pi x)];

eqs1 = s''''[y] - s''''''[y] - s''[y] == 0;

sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {eqs1, s[h1] - F/2 == 0, s'[h1] + 1 == 0, s'''[h1] == 0,
     s[h2] + F/2 == 0, s'[h2] + 1 == 0, s'''[h2] == 0},
    {s}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]

p1 = 
  Plot[Evaluate[{s[y]} /. sol], {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False]

dp = Evaluate[{s'''[y]} /. sol]

delp = NIntegrate[dp, {x, 0.0, 1.0}]
```

Comment: Where did `dpdx` come from?

Comment: It was a typos. It must be dp. I have edited it.

Comment: I see, you are integrating a third derivative. So, why isn't `s''[1] - s''[0]` the integral you need?

Comment: This is an simple example. The original Problem is more complex.Thus I need this to implement it into the original Problem.